# Tor Not Running on Server Always?

Tags: linux, centos, tor

I have a Perl script that uses Tor for scraping certain data.  It was working perfectly and then my script started having issues with scraping.  After a bit of investigation, I realized that Tor wasn't running on the server.

I restarted Tor and the script began running perfectly again.  Any ideas what could have caused this?

Tor is set to automatically start with my server, does it have any crash reports that would be stored on the server or any way for me to check why it wasn't running at that time?

This is on a Linux server with CentOS 6.6 x86_64.  I also have cPanel installed on the server.

Comment: There isn't enough information to even begin to guess at the reason TOR wasn't running at the time.

Comment: Yes... that's why I was asking if there were any log files to find what would have caused it to stop running :)